# Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection - Unsure of what to do

Tags: r, read.csv

I am currently working through Coursera's R Programming course and have hit a bit of a snag with this assignment. I have been getting various errors (not I'm not totally sure I've nailed down) but this is a new one and no matter what I do I can't seem to shake it.
Whenever I run the below code it comes back with

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

```
pollutantmean <- function (directory, pollutant, id){
files<- list.files(path = directory, "/", full.names = TRUE)
dat <- data.frame()
dat <- sapply(file = directory,"/", read.csv)
mean(dat["pollutant"], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

I have tried numerous different solutions posted here on SO for this issue but none of it has worked. I made sure that I am running after setting the working directory to the folder with all of the CSV files and I can see all of the files in the file pane. I have also moved that working directory around a few times since some of the suggestions were to put it on the desktop, etc. but none of that has worked. I am currently running R Studio as an admin but that does not seem to have done anything and I have also modified the permissions on the specdata file to ensure there's no weird restrictions there. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you wish to perform `read.csv` on all file paths listed in the variable `files` you should `sapply(files, read.csv)`, `dat` will then contain a list of data.frames. You will then either need to: 1) combine those data.frames into a single one and find the mean of all values in the 'pollutant' coulmn or 2) `sapply(dat, function(x) mean(x[ , 'pollutant' ], na.rm = TRUE))` to get the mean in the 'pollutant' column for each data.frame

Comment: Also check `?list.files` because passing in "/" the way you are will make list.files use "/" as the "pattern" argument to the function, which I'm guessing is not your intention.

Comment: @br00t Ok, I pulled the "/" so that it does not try to use that as the pattern and I also modified the sapply and added in the second sapply that you suggested. Now I'm getting a new error  `Error in x[, "pollutant"] : incorrect number of dimensions` I think I know what I need to do from here, but I'll play around with it and come back if I have another question. Thank you!

Comment: My apologies Randy Robbins I should have written: `lapply(files, read.csv)`, see my suggested implementations below.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible implementations:

```r
# list all files in "directory", read them, combine and then take mean of "pollutant" column
pollutantmean_1 <- function (directory){
  files <- list.files(path = directory, full.names = TRUE)
  dat <- lapply(file = directory, read.csv)
  dat <- data.table::rbindlist(dat) |> as.data.frame()
  mean(dat[, 'pollutant' ], na.rm = TRUE)
}

# list all files in "directory", read them, take the mean of "pollutant" column for each file and return them
pollutantmean_2 <- function (directory){
  files <- list.files(path = directory, full.names = TRUE)
  dat <- lapply(file = directory, read.csv)
  pollutant_means <- sapply(dat, function(x) mean(x[ , 'pollutant' ], na.rm = TRUE))
  names(pollutant_means) <- basename(files)
  pollutant_means
}
```